# php make multidimensional array with values to keys

Tags: php, arrays, function

I'm trying to show for a php function to make an multidimensional array with values to keys, link this code.

```
 $new_data = array();
        $count = count($params);
        if($count == 1){
            $new_data[$params[0]] = $content; 
        }
        if($count == 2){
            $new_data[$params[0]][$params[1]] = $content; 
        }
        if($count == 3){
            $new_data[$params[0]][$params[1]][$params[2]] = $content; 
        }
        if($count == 4){
            $new_data[$params[0]][$params[1]][$params[2]][$params[3]] = $content; 
        }
        if($count == 5){
            $new_data[$params[0]][$params[1]][$params[2]][$params[3]][$params[4]] = $content; 
        }
```

Comment: You should add an example of the input and the desired output and describe clearly what the current problem is.

Comment: And the question is....?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [Stack Overflow: How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [Jon Skeet's Question Checklist](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist.aspx) to find out how to ask a good question that will generate good useful, answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strangely worded but still a valid question (in my opinion), so I really don't get the downvotes. Anyway, here's one possible solution:

```
function foo($content, $keys) {
  return sizeof($keys) === 0 ? $content : foo([array_pop($keys) => $content], $keys);
}

print_r(foo('bar', ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']));
```

demo: http://3v4l.org/2tcJ5

Comment: thank you, that is what I was looking for. A function that generates an array of n-keys! +1